# Dynamically added form action is not sending parameters javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms

I add form action using jQuery like this:

```
var form = $("<form>", {"class": "thumbnail-custom", "target": "uploadTrg"}).appendTo( thumbnails );
form.attr("action", "http://mysite.fi/admin/php/images.php?action=deleteImage");
```

My PHP looks like this:

```
<?php

    $action = $_GET['action'];

    echo $action;
    echo "hey, what's up";

    return;
?>
```

This prints "hey, what's up" so I know the form is being sent and the link works. For some reason the `echo $action` prints nothing instead of "deleteImage". Why is this happening?

Comment: You're retrieving GET data, while you seem to be interested in the POST data. Try var_dump'ing $_POST.

Comment: have you enable errors?

Comment: I forgot to mark method of the form as "post" when creating it. Would not have figured that out without @NotABlueWhale